# javaFX webengine Fix getDocument returning null on WebEngine Succes

Tags: javafx, javafx-webengine

I'm developing a web crawler for an university project in java.
I use the WebEngine inside an Object called Loader. I use it to download the page trhought the webengine, obtain the Document(org.w3c.dom.document) with WebEngine method getDocument(), the use that document to generate a parsing tree inside the JavaFX thread(becouse WebEngine document cannot be used outside javaFX thread). All of this operation are inside a listener on the WebEngine Worker. I'm also catching the Failed and Cancelled status of the worker to generate a null Parsing Tree.

Sometimes (it's not deterministic) when I submit a VALID URL to the webEngine its worker goes into succeded State, but the getDocument method is returning NULL. For now I'm catching this specific case treating it like Failed.

There is  a way to fix this issue within the java standard library?
Or is an issue in the underlying WebKit implementation?
P.S the webengine is accessed as an AtomicReference.
Code: In the Load(URL url) Method

```
       Platform.runLater(() -> we.get().load(url.toString()));
       //Wait for the listenr to be executed
       Platform.runLater(() -> we.get().load("")); //To Avoid
      submitting the same page twice casung the webengine to be stuck in Running state
        return Result(url, parsing, exception); //It's more complex that this but it's not this that matter
```

In the listener:

```
we.get().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener((o, ov, nv) -> {
            if (nv == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED || nv == Worker.State.FAILED || nv == Worker.State.CANCELLED) {
                if(!we.get().getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("")  && !we.get().getLocation().equalsIgnoreCase("about:blank")) {
                    if (nv == Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                        org.w3c.dom.Document dom = we.get().getDocument();
                        if (dom != null)
                            parser = new Parsing(we.get().getDocument());
                        else
                            nv = Worker.State.FAILED;
                            //THIS: Why on webengine loading completition
                            //the GetDocument() return null, in the  place of the actual document?
                    }
                    downloadRes = nv;
                }
            }
        });
```

Edit: Expliciting setJavaScriptEnabled(false) almost fix this issue.